# Intellij recognizes maven dependency as SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ide, maven-3

I am using **Intellij IDEA 2021.3.1 Community edition** on Linux for one of my Maven project. In the pom.xml file, there is a dependency with `system` scope having version `3.0-20211116.183306-362` as mentioned below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wd.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>wdXml</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/home/mylib/wdXml-3.0-20211116.183306-362.jar</systemPath>
        <version>3.0-20211116.183306-362</version>
    </dependency>
```

The pom.xml does not have any issue, and `mvn package` command runs fine. However, the editor shows compilation errors in the Java class using this dependency.

Upon hours of digging, I found that in the 'Project Dependencies View' Intellij lists this dependency as `com.wd.xml:wdXml:3.0-SNAPSHOT` instead of `com.wd.xml:wdXml:3.0-20211116.183306-362`.

**UPDATE**

I believe it is because of [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) Maven convention

> **version** if you distribute it, then you can choose any typical version with numbers and dots (1.0, 1.1, 1.0.1, ...). **Don't use dates as they are usually associated with SNAPSHOT (nightly) builds**. If it's a third party artifact, you have to use their version number whatever it is, and as strange as it can look. For example,
> 2.0, 2.0.1, 1.3.1

How do I resolve this? Is there any setting in the IDE that can be tweaked.

Comment: Why using a system scoped dependency? Based on the looking of the jar file it is already an outcome of another maven build so you can simply do on that project `mvn install` and use it a usual dependency...

Comment: We receive this jar file from one of our partners.  We prefer not to `mvn install` it in our environment until we sanity test it.

Comment: `Upon hours of digging, I found that in the 'Project Dependencies View' Intellij lists this dependency as com.wd.xml:wdXml:3.0-SNAPSHOT instead of com.wd.xml:wdXml:3.0-20211116.183306-362` the library name is not that important. The important part is - What is the **path** to the jar you see for this dependency? You can see it in the library configuration dialog for this library: https://monosnap.com/file/XWNyo2uKjMpTLdftwwjXJSqmckOlag Also, clarify, does Build | Rebuild action complete successfully? Does `mvn compile` complete successfully?